# Not implemented exception in presentationframework.dll

Tags: wpf, windows

We have an application that uses the Windows Presentation Framework.
One of our users gets a crash on load. The user sent the problem signature to me, and when I looked it up I realised the error was not in our code but rather in the **presentationframework.dll**.
I used **ildasm.exe** to find out what method was failing and it was this one:

```
.method /*06000880*/ public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual 
          instance void  AddPlace(class MS.Internal.AppModel.IShellItem/*020000A9*/ psi,
                                  valuetype [WindowsBase/*23000006*/]MS.Internal.Interop.FDAP/*010000AF*/ fdcp) cil managed
  {
  }
```

It throws a `NotImplementedException`.
The user has the same version of the **presentationframework.dll** as I have, `v4.0.30319` but I have never stumbled upon this error, nor have I heard of any other user that has encountered this. The exact version in the problem signature is `4.0.30319.36366`.

Unfortunately I have no direct access to the users computer, so I cannot investigate further. Does anyone know what might have caused this, or can anyone point me in some direction? I feel kind of lost.

Comment: How does your code call in to that?

Comment: It is a COM interface method, belongs to IFileDialog.  Used in WPF by the OpenFileDialog class and implemented by Windows itself.  Clearly your user needs to get his machine fixed, not something you (or us) can do.

Comment: We never call this method directly, must be used internally somehow. We do use OpenFileDialog however as Hans Passant mentions.
Could patching the .net framework on the users computer fix it perhaps?
edit: accidently posted mid-message

Comment: Do you add any items to the FileDialog.CustomPlaces property by chance? ex. "Favorites" or a "Samples" dir for your app? If so, it could point to a dir or shell item not available on his machine. Permissions difference perhaps?

Comment: I just got more information from the user. Apparently the crash is on startup. So the user doesn't even get the chance to try to upload any files. We do not set anything on FileDialog.CustomPlaces.

Comment: Also would a permissions error cause a NotImplementedException?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Or more information about the cause?

Comment: Hi. I sent the information i got here to the users it department and asked them to get back to me. They have not answered. I guess the problem wasnt so urgent after all. Classic :) 
I Will post an update as soon as I hear something